# Using Python AST Module, parse callables used as arguments

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, python-ast

I'm writing a script that will walk through various Python modules, and hunt for instances of calls to fx.bind(). The first argument to this function is a string representing the hotkey, and the second argument is a function that will be run when the hotkey is pressed. For example, `fx.bind('o', my_func)`.

I have created a subclass of ast.NodeVisitor, that implements visit_Call(), to check all Call nodes. What I'm wondering is how I can parse an actually instance of the callable that's passed as the second argument?

The idea being I can then store my own dictionary, where the keys are the functions, and values are the hotkeys they're assigned too. Ie.`{<function my_func at 0x0>: 'o'}`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import ast
import collections
from typing import Callable
from typing import Any


class NV(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self, module: str, source: ast.AST) -> None:
        self.module = __import__(module)
        self.funcs: dict[Callable[[str], Any], list[str]] = collections.defaultdict(list)
        self.visit(source)

    def visit_Call(self, node: ast.AST) -> None:
        match node:
            case ast.Call(
                func=ast.Attribute(
                    value=ast.Name(id='fx'),
                    attr='bind'
                ),
                args=[
                    ast.Constant(
                        value=cb_value
                    ),
                    ast.Name(
                        id=cb_id
                    )
                ]
            ):
                self.funcs[getattr(self.module, cb_id)].append(cb_value)

            case ast.Call(
                func=ast.Attribute(
                    value=ast.Name(id='fx'),
                    attr='bind'
                ),
                args=[
                    ast.Constant(
                        value=cb_value
                    ),
                    ast.Attribute(
                        value=ast.Name(id=cb_module),
                        attr=cb_id
                    )
                ]
            ):
                module = __import__(cb_module)
                self.funcs[getattr(module, cb_id)].append(cb_value)

        self.generic_visit(node)


with open('pymodule.py') as source_file:
    source_tree = ast.parse(source_file.read())
    node_visitor = NV('pymodule', source_tree)
    print(node_visitor.funcs)
```

**Functionality:**

1. The script visits all `Call`-nodes
2. It checks through the `match`-statement if it is one of the following formats:

   - `fx.bind('o', callback)`
   - `fx.bind('o', other_module.callback)`
3. Further processing:

   - first format: the callback can be found in the same module as the call.
   - second format: the callback needs to be fetched from `other_module`
4. puts the result in the dictionary

**Differences to the needed solution:**

- I felt free to change the wanted `dict` structure to be a `defaultdict`. This prevents overriding when using the same callback twice or more in the same module.

---

**Notes:**

- Explicitly written using Python3.10 using `match`. It can be adjusted to work if `if`-statements, but that would be even messier. If needed though, it is possible.
- It is explicitly not guaranteed that this script is error-free. I could have overlooked edge-cases that I didn't saw reading the question.